# Yii2 Url rules with multiple parameters

Tags: php, regex, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have problem to set url rules with multiple parameters. 
I have the action **"description"** in controller **"Article"** like this:

```
public function actionDescription($aID, $aTitle){ ... }
```

Then i set the url rules like this:

```
 'Article/description/<aID:\d+>/<aTitle:\S+>' => 'article/description',

 '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
 '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
```

When i call a url through a link like this:

```
<?= Html::a( Html::encode($model->aTeaser), 
            ['article/description', 'aID' => $model->aID, 'aTitle' => $model->aTeaser], 
            ['class'=>'link_article'])
                ?>
```

I still get this url:

```
http://test.com/article/description?aID=323&aTitle=teaser+of+this+article
```

instead of this:

```
http://test.com/article/description/323/teaser+of+this+article
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify the escape sequence for the last parameter if you are sure you won't have any parameter after it:

```
'article/description/<aID:\d+>/<aTitle>' => 'article/description'
```

Comment: Thanks. It s working now. I was missing this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you parse the route twice. `Html::a()` is calling `Url::to()` on the URL so there is no need to do it yourself. And what's the deal with empty strings everywhere? It should be:

```
<?= Html::a(
    Html::encode($model->aTeaser), 
    ['article/description', 'aID' => $model->aID, 'aTitle' => $model->aTeaser], 
    ['class' => 'link_article']
) ?>
```

PS. What's the point of second rule with `<aTitle:\s+>` where you try to match all whitespace characters?

Comment: Thanks. Your answer help me understanding that `Html::a()` call `Url::to()`. So i remove  `Url::to()`. But I use @topher answer to get these Urls the way i wanted. Thanks for your help and clean explanation.

Comment: Hmm, really? So just removing `\S+` from the rule and leaving `Url::toRoute()` inside `Html::a()` fixes your problem?

Comment: I  have removed `Url::toRoute()` from `Html::a()` too , before it worked. Both answers were helpful. thanks

Comment: Update your question then.